# Python Variable Assignment If Variable Exists else None in One Line

Tags: python

Can this be done in one line? Something that looks like this `data['x'] = (x if x else "")` (except doesn't raise an exception)

Otherwise I often end up doing the following:

```
try: data['x'] = x
except: data['x'] = ""
```

or for multiple keys initializing with empty values: i.e.

```
data['x'], data['y'] = [], []
```

Comment: Why would `data['x'] = x` raise an exception? You mean `x` might not be set? *Generally*, you'd avoid that kind of situation.

Comment: using globals().get('x', '') ? or locals().get('x', '')

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it's probably a NameError

Comment: @AdamWagner: yeah, I see that. A case of *why not just set `x = ''` and be done with it*.

Comment: right x would not be set (but the key for it needs to be) - it has to do with standardizing form/table types.

Comment: @user3467349, you should generally know if a var exists.  And as Martjin points out, you could just set the value ahead of time to some default value, so you don't get an exception.

Comment: So there's no efficient way to do it in one line? @Adam Wagner - yes I do know if a Var exists, but if it can bet set in a number of different places it is convenient to have i.e. a try block, rather than else statement for everywhere the var could be set but isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out on comments, using probably unset variables is poor form, but if you insist, Luis Masuelli's comment should do the trick:

```
data['x'] = locals().get('x','')  # or globals, depending on the scope you need
```

Comment: I don't see the reason for generalizing 'all possible use cases' to poor form. But that does work, thanks.

Comment: Sure, there are exceptions to everything, but _generally_ it would suggest a flawed design somewhere on the line.